# Is there any way to block flurry?

Tags: applications

I noticed that an app I installed also added Flurry to my phone. I noticed this while doing some development work, and saw some activity relating to Flurry in my `LogCat`. Is there any way to block Flurry from sending reports of information gathered from my phone?

I am waiting for it to send another report, and I will update this question with the exact messages from `LocgCat`.

Answer (score 2):

You could always edit your .hosts file and define the domain the info is being sent to as 127.0.0.1.  You could also use an app like Titanium Backup to "freeze" the app. or chmod it as non-executable yourself.

Comment: Is it necessary to have a rooted phone in order to do this?

Comment: Yes the phone must be rooted.